# error when using waitress-serve code --port 8000

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

**When I use waitress-serve code --port 8000 paper_note:app (paper_note, is the name of my filename) I get an error, that I can't fix**

```
(venv) C:\Users\Paulo\Desktop\Python\projects\paper_note>waitress-serve --port 8000 paper_note:app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Paulo\Desktop\Python\projects\paper_note\venv\Scripts\waitress-serve.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\waitress\runner.py", line 283, in run
    app = resolve(module, obj_name)
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\waitress\runner.py", line 218, in resolve
    obj = __import__(module_name, fromlist=segments[:1])
  File "C:\Users\Paulo\Desktop\Python\projects\paper_note\paper_note.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_migrate import Migrate, upgrade
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from alembic.config import Config as AlembicConfig
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import command
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .script import ScriptDirectory
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import Script  # noqa
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from dateutil import tz
  File "c:\users\paulo\desktop\python\projects\paper_note\venv\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz.py", line 78
    `self._name`,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The `dateutil` package does not have a file called `tz.py`.  `tz` is a separate module, in a directory called `tz`.  I don't know where that file came from, but it's wrong.  Did you copy it there?

Comment: The file tz.py is a module that is automatically installed when I download the python-dateutil package.

Comment: No, it is not.  The dateutil package installs `dateutil\tz\tz.py`, not `dateutil\tz.py`.  The `tz\tz.py` file does not have that line at line 78, nor does it have backticks in any source file at all.  Perhaps you should copy that file somewhere and post a link.  If you have `dateutil\tz\tz.py`, it's likely you need to delete the one in the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error is needed to upgrade python-dateutil to version 2.8.1